# Unexpected border for saved image on IOS Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to save a Relative Layout view (`x:Name="templateView"`) as an image but the image is saving with a border on IOS device. How do I save an image without the border?

Saved image:

[image: Saved image file]

Iphone image preview:

[image: Iphone image preview]

**Page content Xaml:**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid x:Name="templateGrid" BackgroundColor="LightGray">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <local:TemplateView x:Name="templateView" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Frame Grid.Row="0" x:Name="crossButtonFrame"
                                           Padding="15"
                                           Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Start"
                                           HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                           BorderColor="Transparent" CornerRadius="10"
                                           WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"
                                           HasShadow="False" IsVisible="false">
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="CrossButtonClicked" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <Image x:Name="crossButton" Source="crossButton.png"/>
            </Frame>
        <Grid.Effects>
                <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True" TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
            </Grid.Effects>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**Save templateView view as an image:**

I call `GetViewImage` and then `SavePhotoAsync` with the necessary parameters.

```
public byte[] GetViewImage(View view)
    {
        try
        {
            var size = new Size(view.Width, view.Height);
            var rect = new CGRect(view.X, view.Y, size.Width, size.Height);
            var iOSView = ConvertFormsToNative(view, rect);

            UIImage uiImage = ConvertViewToImage(iOSView, rect);

            byte[] bitmapData;

            var png = uiImage.AsPNG();
            bitmapData = png.ToArray();

            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

            return bitmapData;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static UIView ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, CGRect size)
    {
        try
        {
            var renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(view);

            renderer.NativeView.Frame = size;

            renderer.NativeView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
            renderer.NativeView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;

            renderer.Element.Layout(size.ToRectangle());

            var nativeView = renderer.NativeView;

            nativeView.SetNeedsLayout();

            return nativeView;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private UIImage ConvertViewToImage(UIView iOSView, CGRect size)
    {
        try
        {
            CGSize s = new CGSize(size.Width, size.Height);
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(s, opaque: false, scale: 0);

            iOSView.Layer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
            UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            return image;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

public Task<bool> SavePhotoAsync(byte[] data, string folder, string filename)
    {
        NSData nsData = NSData.FromArray(data);
        UIImage image = new UIImage(nsData);
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((UIImage img, NSError error) =>
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(error == null);
        });

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
```

Comment: What about reduce the Y when get rect:   `var rect = new CGRect(view.X, view.Y - 64, size.Width, size.Height);`.

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT But it's just move the view up. Seems the problem in the view dimensions.

Comment: Are you saving the "crossButton" view or the wrapper?..

Comment: @NickKovalsky I'm saving the 'templateView'

Comment: One workaround I thought is crop the image again after you get the image with unexpected border in iOS.